# Linking MongoDB and SQL Server using mongodb connector for BI

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, odbc

I want to add MongoDB server to SQL Server as a linked server. That's why I need ODBC being set up and fed by the MongoDB connector for BI. When I install and set it up its just not visible in the ODBC admin. Do you know what might be wrong?

I have tried with:

1. Mongodb connector for bi 1.2 - Once installed its visible in the ODBC admin but i cant make set it up as to connect to the MongoDB instance
2. Mongodb connector for bi 2.11 - Installed and set up properly its just not visible in the ODBC system DSN tab
3. Progress Data Direct Driver - perfectly working its just not free of charge

Output:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Connector for BI\2.1\bin>net start mongosql
The MongoSQL Service service is starting.
The MongoSQL Service service was started successfully.
```

This is the last stage of setting up the mongodb connector for bi before adding it in the ODBC SystemDSN tab

My task is to sync MongoDB and SQL Server for analysis and reporting purposes. Trying to do it vie linked server and i am stuck in setting up the mongodb connector. Any feedback or workaround on the topic would be more than welcome